# how to attach AWS scp-organization unit's (OUs) policies to particular organization unit(OU) using python script?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-sdk, boto3, pyyaml

YAML file:

```
     Organization-unit:
      xyz
     Organization-unit:
      xyz2

     Policies:
     - name: scp-xyz
       description:
     - name: scp-xyz2
       description:
```

using python how to attach xyz organization unit to scp-xyz only under aws organization.

output: list of policies and organization unit info

```
{'Policies': [{'Id': 'p-xw7j86as', 'Arn': '', 'Name': 'scp-xyz', 'Description': 'Allows access to every operation', 'Type': 'SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY', 'AwsManaged': True}
{'Policies': [{'Id': 'p-xw7j006as', 'Arn': '', 'Name': 'scp-xyz2', 'Description': 'Allows access to every operation', 'Type': 'SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY', 'AwsManaged': True}

{'OrganizationalUnit': {'Id': 'ou-uwjh-87', 'Arn': 'a', 'Name': 'xyz'} 
{'OrganizationalUnit': {'Id': 'ou-uw-87', 'Arn': 'a', 'Name': 'xyz2'}
```

I have below sample to attach policy to OU:

```
   response = client.attach_policy(
    PolicyId='string', #policy ID string requires "p-" followed by from 8 to 
                       128 lower-case letters or digits.
    TargetId='string' # ID of OU
   )
```

Can anyone please guide me how can I do this task ?

**REsult should be like below :**

```
    [![SCP-xyz policy should attach with xyz organization unit][1]][1]
```

[image][image]

Comment: The result is valid YAML, but only if parsed on its own. Please provide the complete output that you expect, and make sure that is valid YAML. It is also unclear to me (but maybe that is because I don't know boto3 and aws-sdk) how the output and the result are related. And is PyYAMLrequired (it drops a lot of useful information and formatting if you use it to  load-modify-dump YAML). Why the tags Python-3.x and Python-2.7? If this needs to run on both use the Python tag. Please put more effort in creating good questions (formatting, understandable, appropriate tags)